# What's the regex expression to split string by these special characters (such as squared brackets [] and dashes / \)?

Tags: regex

I want to split some string such as "[MX0149/M4200], and total\test//now" this should output: MX0149 M4200 and total test now.

So far my regex expression is as follow: [\s@&.,;><_=()!?/$#+-]+ but I want it to include splitting string by squared brackets [] and dashes / .

Comment: Since dashes and brackets are reserved regex characters, you'll likely just need to escape them with a back-slash, e.g. `\[`.

Comment: Splitting `[MX0149/M4200]` will leave you with empty tokens as well because you have `[` and `]` at start and end. I feel match should be a better option, if you know the character set you want to capture. Else after splitting, you will have to discard empty values programmatically.

Comment: Also, what language you are using?

Comment: I'm using java .

Comment: @junior: I've posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55968248/2102956). Please check and it it works for you then please accept the answer which will reward  you with +2 reputation as well as help someone else easily locating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\W+` (which is same as `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`) to split your string and get your desired output.

Check this Java code,

```
String s = "[MX0149/M4200], and total\\test//now";
Arrays.stream(s.split("\\W+"))
.filter(x -> x.length() > 0) // this is to remove empty string as first string will be empty
.forEach(System.out::println); // print all the splitted strings
```

Prints,

```
MX0149
M4200
and
total
test
now
```

Let me know if this works for you.